# variables within bracket followed by braces es6

Tags: javascript, node.js

What is the effect of the following bracket followed by a braces (eg     ({user}) below)?

```
promise1.then(user => ({user}));
```

Comment: create an object?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's a shorthand for returning an object literal - your code is functionally the same as this:

```
promise1.then(user => {
    return {
        user: user
    };
});
```

For more info on this syntax, see the MDN article on [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#Returning_object_literals). Also, note that your code is making use of the [property name shorthand](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#New_notations_in_ECMAScript_2015) too.

Comment: It's interesting that `user => {{user}}` doesn't work, but it also doesn't cause a syntax error. It just fails silently.

Comment: @evolutionxbox: Huh, yeah, that is surprising.